# What did the author mean by "before it became too late" in the following passage?

Tags: meaning

For context, the character Matt Kellner had been abducted by a serial killer. Matt Kellner did not know he had been targeted for abduction.

*"What kept weighing me down with fright was that I knew that something had been happening to Matt that caused him to disappear—I believed there were forces beyond Matt’s control that led to his disappearance and had been circling him weeks before he was “officially” missing. There was no other angle from which I could look at what happened to Matt Kellner: he had been targeted, and these forces entered into his life and **before it became too late** to figure any of this out they had simply taken him."*

Comment: The word *before* seems out of place: "Forces entered into his life and it became too late ..."

Comment: [“before it became too late“](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=67c93a61bbf2e847&sxsrf=ACQVn0_4QOu2ROuvzJdU9TLX5wQn3iHeKQ:1707977930942&q=%22before+it+became+too+late%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIj-7O2ayEAxXw1gIHHcgJA3EQ0pQJegQIXRAB&biw=1151&bih=630&dpr=2.5) I see nothing weird or out of place in the quotation.

Comment: I think the author means “before there was time”. So it’s grammatical but not logical.  Writing intended to be fast-moving but isn’t really good.

Comment: Once he had been abducted, it was too late for him to work out that he was at risk of abduction.

Comment: You don't provide enough context. It's not clear who is doing the figuring out, the forces or Kellner. But one possible context would be this: Kellner was trying to figure something out that would prevent a crime. If he was too slow, it would be too late to figure anything out and the crime would occur, so they could have waited and trusted he would be too late. But before it was too late to take action on this, i.e. before the crime, they abducted him.

Comment: OK - with the additional context, it was too late for _the narrator_ to work it out.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speaker is saying that they had simply taken him *before it became too late* (for me) to figure out what was going on.  That is, *while I still had time to figure it out*.

Is the speaker "beating himself up" about his failure to figure it all out?

It is an illogical thought process, since by the time he was abucted it was indeed "too late" -- if the measure of timeliness was  figuring it out and preventing it.